# Assigning pixels to their local maximum matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, pixel

I need to assign pixels to their local maximum in matlab. I can easily find the local maxima in matlab using imregional max or other derivatives such as extrema2. However, I also want to cluster the pixels based on these local maxima.

For example, if I have a peak then I also want to know if the pixels surrounding this peaks are connected to the maxima. I cant think of any efficient ways of doing this and any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: are local minima also of importance?

Comment: No only the maxima - although it would be preferable for the pixels on the slope of a valley to be assigned to the maxima of the peak on which they reside

Comment: What does "connected" mean?

Comment: I ain't sure what you mean with your second abstract. My guess is: Lets say you have two 2d-gaussians peaks and everything else is around 0. Now you want to give each element which is part of peak1 the max-value of that peak and same for the second peak. If that is right could you either use further information of your data OR could you look at the second derivative to get the "acceleration, deceleration"?

Comment: Hi, yes I think I am confusing myself. Ill ass an image to demonstrate what I am trying to do.

Comment: I cant add images so Ill share a link

Comment: I cant find a good example either. If you imagine an image that contains many blobs and for each of these blobs I know where their local maxima resides. For all those pixels that are less than the maximum and still part of the peak I would like to assign an unique identifier. If I come to a point where I am ascending another peak then I need to make a new label as this is a new peak. Thanks for all the input guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you could limit the question to "does the pixel belong to the previous local maximum or to the next one?" and then look at the derivatives (gradients) of the pixels: if negative, it belongs to the previous, if positive it belongs to the next one :)

Following image

[image]

with maxima  `Max1=[17,59]` and `Max2=[83,59]`

and the idea I mentioned for the dimension X:

```
Pixel=[randi(100),randi(100)];

[XG,YG]=imgradientxy(Image);

Maxima=[Max1;Max2];

ii=1;
while Pixel(1)>Maxima(ii,1);
    ii=ii+1;
end

if XG(Pixel)>0
    LocalMax=Maxima(ii,:);
else
    LocalMax=Maxima(ii-1,:);
end

imshow(Image);hold on

plot(Pixel(1),Pixel(2),'r.');
plot(LocalMax(1),LocalMax(2),'gx');
```

will (sometimes) give you results like this:[image]

It's just a sketch of  my idea, not robust by anymeans, and probably with a couple of erros, so don't go copy-pasting it. You still have the homework to implement that for the 2 dimensional scenario ;)

Comment: Upsss... got a small error with the indexing of 'ii', but you got the idea, right?